# Не удаляется значение из реестра

Tags: c#, реестр

Пытаюсь удалить значение из ветки реестра. Запустил `Visual Studio` из под админа. При попытке удаление пишет `{"Не удалось выполнить запись в раздел реестра."}`

```
 private static void SearchSubKeys(RegistryKey root, string searchKey)
        {

            if (root == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (string keyname in root.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (RegistryKey key = root.OpenSubKey(keyname,true))
                    {
                        if (key == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }


                        var z = key.GetValueNames().Where(x => x.Contains("axi")).ToList();

                        if (z.Count > 0)
                        {
                            key.DeleteValue("axi",true);

                        }

                        if (keyname.Contains(searchKey))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                //root.DeleteSubKeyTree(searchKey);

                                string logPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\FClassroom\Config\CleanRegistry.log";

                                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logPath))
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", keyname, key.Name, root.Name));
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                        }

                        SearchSubKeys(key, searchKey);
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Security.SecurityException se)
                {

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако если сделать, то все работает без ошибок.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"BCD00000000\Description", true);
key.DeleteValue("axi", true);
```

Comment: Попробуйте запустить не VS с правами администратора, а приложение которое вы скопмпилировали.

Comment: пытался. Тоже самое

Answer (score 1):

какая ветка? для HKLM нужны права администратора.
В методе OpenSubKey измените вызов

```
using (RegistryKey key = root.OpenSubKey(keyname, true))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: запустил от админа vs. Тоже самое

Comment: @Radzhab а метод не чувствителен к регистру (в коде "Axi" в скриншоте "axi") ? какой тип эксепшена бросает при удалении?

Comment: в System.ThrowHelper.ThrowUnauthorizedAccessException(ExceptionResource resource)
   в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.EnsureWriteable()
   в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.DeleteValue(String name)
   в RegKeyRemover.Program.SearchSubKeys(RegistryKey root, String searchKey) в C:\Users\radzhab\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\RegKeyRemover\RegKeyRemover\Program.cs:строка 38

Comment: @Radzhab у вас ключ открыт только для чтения, дополнил ответ, МСДН как раз четко по эксепшену подсказывает для метода удаления https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dk8b3th2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Вся проблема кроется в том что я не могу передать параметр trus в GetSubKeyNames

Comment: не понял, при чем здесь GetSubKeyNames, он не открывает ключ, а просто получает массив строк, ключ же открывается методом OpenSubKey, в вашем случае он открывается только на чтение

Comment: Поправил код.  Он не работает, однако если указать  то все пашет                           
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"BCD00000000\Description", true);
key.DeleteValue("axi", true);

Comment: что именно не работает? эксепшен? какой именно?